# Using localtime in a where clause for GqlQuery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gqlquery

I'm trying to understand how I can use the local server time to quickly filter results on google appengine. It seems to me that there should be a simple way of doing this using DATETIME(time.localtime()).

For example (where 'timestamp' is of type db.DateTimeProperty)...

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LiveData WHERE timestamp > DATETIME(:1)", time.localtime())
```

Is there a GqlQuery and/or python construct that lets me do this with one method call? It seems as though I need to create strings for DATETIME() parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to create strings when querying `DateTimeProperty` types.  Try this:

```
import datetime
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LiveData WHERE timestamp > :1", datetime.datetime.now())
```